# Error: trying to use olsrr library in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, libraries

I am trying to import olsrr library using jupyter notebook, but writing library(olsrr) I get an error message: 
Error in library(olsrr): there is no package called ‘olsrr’
Traceback:

1. library(olsrr)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)

I've already installed the package without any problems, both using R studio and jupyter. May I ask you for help?

Comment: did you tell jupyter that you are executing an R command ?

Comment: How can I do it? Anyway, all the notebook is working (with R code), and all other libraries are fine. Thank you!